# what is -moz in css

Tags: css

I have seen  some css files use `-moz` , but I have never used it.

Can anyone tell me what is that and why is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're Gecko-specific properties. They're used to invoke Gecko-specific behavior, or behavior that isn't implemented in other layout engines.

Comment: what are Gecko means?? sorry if it is so trivial.

Answer (score 4):

CSS properties that get only processed by the gecko engine (e.G: Firefox). THat's part of the CSS standard, so that you can set specific properties for a browser without disrupting the others.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answer the "what" question. As for the "why", [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/) has written an [interesting **article on vendor prefixes**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prefix-or-posthack/)—*Prefix or Posthack*—on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).